# not able to pass array from controller to view in cakephp 3 using $this->set('data', array received from find())

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Not able to pass array variable form controller to view below code
If, I print in controller it is showing "Undefined variable: data"

```
public function report(){
$results=$this->Nodals->find()->toArray();
$this->set('data',$results);
print_r($data); die();}
```

Comment: `$data` will not be set in the controller by this, only in the view when it renders.

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: What issue, exactly? Your problem is not clear. The `set` call as you have written it will result in a variable called `$data` being available in your view. If you want it available in your controller, it's already there, it's just called `$results`. If you need it to be called `$data` for some reason, then just rename the variable.

Comment: In the above code $data will always undefined if you use in controller because $this->set()  set $data to use in view file not in controller. 
You need to use $result if you are using in controller. 

For view file : print($data) 
For controller : print($result)

Comment: Thanks problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try using `compact` like this.

`public function report(){
  $data=$this->Nodals->find()->toArray();
  $this->set(compact('data'));
 };`

Now do `dd` in your view to check if the `data` variable sending to the view. I am assuming your view file is `report.ctp`, so in `report.ctp` file write this line

```
<?php
  dd($data);
?>
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: In the view, this code will have the exact same result as the original posted code.

Answer (score 0):

$data is not defined in your code if you want to print the query result from 
$this->Nodals->find()->toArray(); then you need to store this in $data variable or any other variable

```
$results=$this->Nodals->find()->toArray();
$this->set('data',$results);

//data will be sent to the template which wrap the $result and in template you can access $reseult by using $data
print_r($results); 
die();
```

or

```
$data=$this->Nodals->find()->toArray();
$this->set('data',$data);
print_r($data); 
die();
```